# Screen space raycasting

Tags: ios, opengl-es-2.0, raycasting

I am using OpenGL ES 2.0 and the latest iOS.

I have a 3D model that I wish the user to be able to select different parts of the model by tapping on the screen.  I have found [this](http://www.mvps.org/directx/articles/rayproj.htm) tutorial on converting a pixel-space screen coordinate to a world-space ray, and have implemented a ray-AABB intersection test to determine the intersection portion of the model.

I get **some** hits on the model at seemingly random sections of the model.  So I need to debug this feature, but I don't really know where to start.

I can't exactly draw a line representing the ray (since it is coming out of the camera it will appear as a point), so I can see a couple of ways of debugging this:

1. Check the bounding boxes of the model sections.  So is there an easy way with OGL ES to draw a bounding box given a min and max point?
2. draw some 3D object along the path of the ray.  This seems more complicated.
3. Actually debug the raycast and intersection code.  This seems like the hardest to accomplish since the algorithms are fairly well known (I took the intersection test straight ouf of my Real-Time Collision Detection book).

If anyone can help, or wants me to post some code, I could really use it.

Here is my code for converting to world space:

```
- (IBAction)tappedBody:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    if ( !editMode )
    {
        return;
    }
    CGPoint tapPoint = [sender locationOfTouch:0 inView:self.view];
    const float tanFOV = tanf(GLKMathDegreesToRadians(65.0f*0.5f));
    const float width = self.view.frame.size.width,
                height = self.view.frame.size.height,
                aspect = width/height,
                w_2 = width * 0.5,
                h_2 = height * 0.5;

    CGPoint screenPoint;
    screenPoint.x = tanFOV * ( tapPoint.x / w_2 - 1 ) / aspect;
    screenPoint.y = tanFOV * ( 1.0 - tapPoint.y / h_2 );

    GLKVector3 nearPoint = GLKVector3Make(screenPoint.x * NEAR_PLANE, screenPoint.y * NEAR_PLANE, NEAR_PLANE );
    GLKVector3 farPoint = GLKVector3Make(screenPoint.x * FAR_PLANE, screenPoint.y * FAR_PLANE, FAR_PLANE );

    GLKVector3 nearWorldPoint = GLKMatrix4MultiplyVector3( _invViewMatrix, nearPoint );
    GLKVector3 farWorldPoint = GLKMatrix4MultiplyVector3( _invViewMatrix, farPoint );

    GLKVector3 worldRay = GLKVector3Subtract(farWorldPoint, nearWorldPoint);
    NSLog(@"Model matrix: %@", NSStringFromGLKMatrix4(_modelMatrix));
    worldRay = GLKVector4Normalize(worldRay);

    [male intersectWithRay:worldRay fromStartPoint:nearWorldPoint];

    for ( int i =0; i < 3; ++i )
    {
        touchPoint[i] = nearWorldPoint.v[i];
    }
}
```

And here's how I get the matrices:

```
- (void)update
{
//  _rotation = 0;

    float aspect = fabsf(self.view.bounds.size.width / self.view.bounds.size.height);
    GLKMatrix4 projectionMatrix = GLKMatrix4MakePerspective(GLKMathDegreesToRadians(65.0f), aspect, NEAR_PLANE, FAR_PLANE);

    self.effect.transform.projectionMatrix = projectionMatrix;
    GLKMatrix4 baseModelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4MakeTranslation(0.0f, 0.0f, -5.0f);

    // Compute the model view matrix for the object rendered with ES2
    _viewMatrix = GLKMatrix4MakeTranslation(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    _modelMatrix = GLKMatrix4Rotate(baseModelViewMatrix, _rotation, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    _modelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4Rotate(_viewMatrix, _rotation, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    _modelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4Multiply(baseModelViewMatrix, _modelViewMatrix);

    _invViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4Invert(_viewMatrix, NULL);
    _invMVMatrix = GLKMatrix4Invert(_modelViewMatrix, NULL);

    _normalMatrix = GLKMatrix3InvertAndTranspose(GLKMatrix4GetMatrix3(_modelViewMatrix), NULL);

    _modelViewProjectionMatrix = GLKMatrix4Multiply(projectionMatrix, _modelViewMatrix);

    male.modelTransform = _modelMatrix;

    if ( !editMode )
    {
        _rotation += self.timeSinceLastUpdate * 0.5f;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why this fixed the problem I was having but changing

```
screenPoint.x = tanFOV * ( tapPoint.x / w_2 - 1 ) / aspect;
```

to

```
screenPoint.x = tanFOV * ( tapPoint.x / w_2 - 1 ) * aspect;
```

and

```
GLKVector4 nearPoint = GLKVector4Make(screenPoint.x * NEAR_PLANE, screenPoint.y * NEAR_PLANE, NEAR_PLANE, 1 );
GLKVector4 farPoint = GLKVector4Make(screenPoint.x * FAR_PLANE, screenPoint.y * FAR_PLANE, FAR_PLANE, 1 );
```

to

```
GLKVector4 nearPoint = GLKVector4Make(screenPoint.x * NEAR_PLANE, screenPoint.y * NEAR_PLANE, -NEAR_PLANE, 1 );
GLKVector4 farPoint = GLKVector4Make(screenPoint.x * FAR_PLANE, screenPoint.y * FAR_PLANE, -FAR_PLANE, 1 );
```

seems to have fixed the raycasting issue.  Still not sure why my view matrix seems to be indicating that the camera is looking down the positive Z-axis, but my objects are translated negative along the z axis

Answer (score 0):

> I can't exactly draw a line representing the ray (since it is coming
>   out of the camera it will appear as a point)

Don´t discard this so soon. Isn't it that what you are trying to test? I mean, That would be so if you are unprojecting things right. But if it you have a bug, it won't.

I'll go with this first... if you see a point just under your finger the conversion is right, and you can start investigating the other options you pointed out, which are more complex.

Comment: Draw it at the world-space coordinates I calculate?

Comment: Yes. You can also draw the screen-space point if you want. It should also be under your finger together with the "line-point". If that works, it would mean that your conversion code is completely correct.. almost "by definition".

Comment: Well, the world space point isn't at all drawing in the right place, I added some code to my question, can you spot anything that seems outright wrong with my calculations?

Comment: Oh shoot, the world-space point its drawing is applying the model's transform instead of just the view-projection transform, let me fix that and see if it helps

Comment: I can't find the problem. Your code seems to be loyal to the tutorial. There are some thing that i dont quite understand in the tutorial (like the division by ASPECT). May be you can try another tutorial. I think you can get both intersection points using GLKMathUnproject (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11056391/how-to-use-glkmathunproject).

Comment: I have managed to find the glaring errors that were actually in my intersection function.  But the last problem I can't seem to resolve is now my ray seems to be pointing int he wrong direction.  Given the matrices above, what seems wrong with my transformations that would cause my object to be along the negative z axis, but the ray to go along the positive z axis?  (Which of those two is the wrong thing?

Comment: worldRay = GLKVector3Subtract(farWorldPoint, nearWorldPoint); does farPoint-NearPoint, so it creates a ray that goes from the far plane to near plane (It comes out of the screen). You can reverse it by switching the parameters.

Comment: `farPoint-nearPoint` should give a vector pointing from `nearPoint` to `farPoint` (`(farPoint-nearPoint) + nearPoint = farPoint`)

Comment: i'll go back to school!! sorry for that! :(. In that case, why do you say your model is along negative z axis?. If rotation is 0, you are putting your camera at z=-5 looking towards positive z.

Comment: I say it is negative z based on the model's translation transform